# serialize and deserialize an ActiveRecord scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We're trying to find an efficient way to pass a number of records to a background job in Rails. The goal is that inside the job we have a scope so that we can tack on `.includes` and so forth. Right now the best we have is to `User.active.pluck(:id)` on the client and inside the job `User.where(id: passed_in_ids)`. I'm wondering if there's any way to actually serialize the scope and reconstitute it inside of the job.

I could see using `User.active.to_sql` on the client, but then inside the job the only option I see is `User.find_by_sql(passed_in_query)`, but that returns an array and not an AR scope. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do here. Maybe avoid the problem altogether and serialize whatever data is used to build the query and then apply the query building login inside the background job.

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate the `ActiveRecord` relation with `User.unscoped.from("(#{passed_in_query}) users")`. You'll lose the eager loaded associations though, but it's probably the job's responsibility to load those.

There's probably a cleaner way to achieve what you want, but it's hard to say without access to the code that schedules the background job. I'm guessing encapsulating the query you first built inside a scope that could be reused in the job.